# Accesing data from a form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have to create a small project with ado.net and asp.net mvc 4.I am at a point where I have to insert data into a database , witch should not be a problem if I could just figure out how to acces the posted data.

This is my code:

```
public ActionResult AddBook()
{
    return View(books);
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <label for="BookName">Book Name:</label><input type="text" name="BookName" />
    <label for="Author">Author:</label><input type="text" name="Author" />
    <label for="Description">Book Name:</label><input type="text" name="BookName" />
    <label>Choose category:</label>
    <select>
          @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Categories.Rows) { 
                <option value="@row["Id"]">@row["CategoryName"]</option>
          }
    </select>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

How can I acces the posted data?

Comment: posted data means ? you want to call action on submit button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have not binded your view to `Model` class, you can access the form values using `Request.Form[]`.

This is how you do it:

```
public ActionResult AddBook(FormCollection collection)
{
    var bookname=collection.Get["BookName"];//here book name is the name of your input element
    ... similarily the rest
    ... do some database stuff
    return View();
}
```

or

```
public ActionResult AddBook()
{
    var bookname=Request.Form["BookName"];//here book name is the name of your input element
    ... similarily the rest
    ... do some database stuff
    return View();
}
```